# Vertica - is there a way to execute copy command even though there are error records in csv?

Tags: vertica

I wonder if there is a way to execute copy command even though there are error records in csv?

(something like max error rejected count)?

..so if i have 100 records, 9 of them are invalid & max rejected is 10
the file will upload..

if so can you provide copy command for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The REJECTMAX parameter specifies a limit for rejected records.  According to the [documentation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/BulkLoadCOPY/CapturingLoadExceptionsAndRejections.htm) the limit is one lower; when rejections reach REJECTMAX the COPY aborts.  So in your case you want to set REJECTMAX to 10.

Consider using this in combination with REJECTED DATA, which specifies where to log rejections.